# Running Docker command in java

Tags: java, linux, docker, docker-java

I'm trying to run this command in docker trough java, but i don't know why it only works when i execute the command in the host machine and not trough java (when execute on java it doesn't add or say nothing). i'm 99% sure problem are the ">>" of the echo but i don't know how to fix it.

```
    private void doCommand(){
    
    String command = "docker exec -i -t vsftpd bash -c 'echo -e \"myuser5\\nmypass\" >> /etc/vsftpd/virtual_users.txt'";

    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        
        Process process = pb.start();

        InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error has been resolved, fixed by using https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).